# Get a configuration option from node type structure

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm working on a module and was wondering how to get a node type setting (that was set when creating the node type at: admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR-TYPE) inside a node creating/editing page.

I added a node structure setting with the hook: mymodule_form_node_type_form_alter() and now I want to check if this option is active when creating/editing a node, hook: mymodule_form_node_form_alter()

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. Can you include the code you used to add the setting?

Comment: Moved the comment to answer, so this doesnt have to stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node type forms save their data in variable table prefixed with form field name and suffix will be node type.

If field was `$form['MY_SETTING']=array(...);` you can get the value with `variable_get('MY_SETTING_' . $node->type, '');`